# How to fix this error "error: no matching function for call to 'getline(std::ifstream&, st::_cx11::string&,

Tags: c++

How to fix this error?

> error: no matching function for call to 'getline(std::ifstream&, st::_cx11::string&, const char[2]' getline(fine, stockNames, ":");

I am getting this error when trying to compile on mimir.io. Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include<fstream>
using std::ofstream;
using std::ifstream;

#include<string>
using std::string;

int main()
{
   ifstream fin("spFileIOstockData.txt");
   if (fin)
   {
       string stockNames;
       getline (fin, stockNames, ":");
       cout << stockNames;
   }
    else 
        cout << "Unable to open spFileIIOStock.txt. Exiting... \n\n";

return 0;    
}
```

I am trying to write my code so that it will input text from a text file.

I've tried Googling, with no results so far. I've tried retyping the code three times (based on a code snippet I got as a handout).

Comment: Did you read the [Documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)? The delimiter is a char, not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) takes in the following parameters :

input   -   the stream to get data from

str -   the string to put the data into

delim   -   the delimiter character

In your call for `getline`, the third parameter (delim) is supposed to be a character, while you are passing `":"` as a string by using double quotes.
Pass `':'` using single quotes instead of double quotes, it should resolve the error.

```
getline (fin, stockNames, ':');
```